# Using Mobx inject store with Typescript and React stateless component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, mobx, mobx-state-tree

I'm using mobx-state-tree library with react and typescript.

Store.ts:

```
import { types } from 'mobx-state-tree'

export const UserModel = types
  .model('UserModel', {
    name: types.maybe(types.string)
  });

const RootStore = types
  .model('RootStore', {
    user: types.optional(types.maybe(UserModel), null)
  });

export default RootStore
```

App.jsx stateless component:

```
const App = ({ rootStore }: {rootStore: typeof RootStore.Type}) =>
  <Wrapper>
    Content
  </Wrapper>;

export default inject('rootStore')(observer(App))
```

When i'm trying to add App component into root component i'm getting typescript compiler error

> Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { rootStore: { user: { name: any; } & IStateTreeNode; } & IStateTreeNode; }'.

```
const rootStore = RootStore.create();

render(
  <AppContainer>
    <Provider rootStore={rootStore}>
      <App/> // <- the error was thrown out here
    </Provider>
  </AppContainer>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

RootStore injected by Provider mobx component which uses React context mechanism to inject rootStore into child components. But it looks like typescript compiler does not know about this mechanism and throws error because rootStore must be explicitly provided by root component.

What do i should to add to show typescript that rootStore will be provided by mobx provider ?

Comment: jup this is a long issue, if you search for it on the internet you get a lot of results

Comment: @JoelHarkes thanks for link on github issue, solution on this comment worked for me: https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react/issues/256#issuecomment-335301953